# Shrinking dataset to group individual data for one day using groupby and aggregate functions

Tags: python, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have 2 datasets for which there are multiple repeated rows for each date due to different recording time of each health attribute pertaining to that date.

I want to shrink my dataset to aggregate the values of each column pertaining to the same day. I don't want to create a new data frame because I need to then merge the datasets with other datasets. After trying the code below, my df's shape still returns the same number of rows. Any help would be appreciated.

**sample data:**

[Data Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCv4K.png)

[Output snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C80Q1.png)

```
count calorie  update_time               speed        distance    date
101   4.290000  2018-04-30 18:35:00.291 1.527778    78.420000   2018-04-30
25    0.960000  2018-04-13 19:55:00.251 1.027778    14.360000   2018-04-13
38    1.530000  2018-04-02 10:14:58.210 1.194444    24.190000   2018-04-02
35    1.450000  2018-04-27 10:55:01.281 1.500000    27.450000   2018-04-27
0     0.000000  2018-04-21 13:46:36.801 0.000000    0.000000    2018-04-21
34  1.820000    2018-04-01 08:35:05.481 2.222222    30.260000   2018-04-01

df_SC['date']=df_SC.groupby('date').agg({"distance": "sum","calorie":"sum",
                                         "count":"sum","speed":"mean"}).reset_index()
```

expect *sum of distance*, *calorie*, *count* and *mean of speed* to show up under each respective column and against each data.

Comment: Please share some sample data

Comment: I have embedded the data frame head that show the columns and shape which should reduce if all attributes were combined in one cell against each date rather than each date repeating more than once

Comment: Please do not past screencaps - copy and paste some sample data so we can work with it.

Comment: Also, what output are you getting?

Comment: Apologies but can't seem to plug the data in a table for legibility reasons (new to SO). The output returns lots of NaN values which I assume are for the repetitive dates whereas I expected those rows to have been deleted or dataset compressed; I have added a snapshot of this, as well. The code does return does return 34 unique dates in the column however and 9724 NaN values (of 9758 original sample)

Comment: I think the problem is that you're attempting to add a column to your df, which Pandas automatically pads with NaNs to fit the rest of the df. Maybe what you want instead is a [pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html). I don't understand what you mean by "I don't want to create a new data frame because I need to then merge the datasets with other datasets" - couldn't you still do that with a new df?

Comment: Yes, I will either create a new data frame figuring out the right key to merge with the rest of the datasets that come in one format, or delete the rows that have duplicated dates post aggregating the info for each date.